# np.argsort() in tight rank

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

How does `np.argsort()` work with the ties?

```
test = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
np.argsort(test)
```

Why does index 20 come first in the result?

I have checked other resources, but could not find an explanation. Are the indices randomly assigned where there are ties? Thanks!

```
array([20,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 23, 17, 14, 15,  0, 22, 21, 19, 18, 12,
       13,  7,  6,  3,  2,  1, 16, 24], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`numpy.argsort()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) returns the indices of the array that would sort the array elements. In case of the presence of duplicated entries, the returned indices is dependent on the type of the sorting algorithm that is used to sort the array. Based on this selection, you might see different results, as can be observed below:

```
# input
In [90]: a
Out[90]: 
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.,
       0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.])

# more intuitive
In [85]: np.argsort(a, kind='mergesort')
Out[85]: 
array([ 4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 20, 23,  0,  1,  2,  3,  6,  7,
       12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 21, 22, 24])

# default choice
In [86]: np.argsort(a, kind='quicksort')
Out[86]: 
array([20,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 23, 17, 14, 15,  0, 22, 21, 19, 18, 12,
       13,  7,  6,  3,  2,  1, 16, 24])

In [88]: np.argsort(a, kind='heapsort')
Out[88]: 
array([17, 11, 20,  8, 15, 14, 23, 10,  4,  9,  5, 13,  6, 12, 24,  2, 21,
       19, 18, 16,  7, 22,  3,  1,  0])

# more intuitive
In [89]: np.argsort(a, kind='stable')
Out[89]: 
array([ 4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 20, 23,  0,  1,  2,  3,  6,  7,
       12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 21, 22, 24])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not one answer to this:

```py
>>> np.argsort(test, kind="quicksort")
array([20,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 23, 17, 14, ... ])
>>> np.argsort(test, kind="mergesort")
array([ 4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 20, ... ])
>>> np.argsort(test, kind="stable")
array([ 4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 20, ... ])
>>> np.argsort(test, kind="heapsort")
array([17, 11, 20,  8, 15, 14, 23, 10,  4,  9, ... ])
```

I guess we could [read the code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/core/src/npysort) to really understand why this happens, but my best guess is that the order is arbitrary and is probably a consequence not a choice.

On the other hand, if you need to have a custom sub-sort for ties, you can maybe use `np.unique`. As an example I'll just sort the output of `quicksort` so it mimics the output of say `mergesort`:

```py
ranks = np.argsort(test, kind="quicksort")
# split the indexes so we can sort them independently:
_, counts = np.unique(test, return_counts=True)
cuts = np.cumsum(counts)[:-1]
rank_bins = np.split(ranks, cuts)
sorted_rank_bins = [np.sort(b) for b in rank_bins]
# glue them back together: 
ranks = np.concatenate(sorted_rank_bins)
```

Now `ranks` contains:

```py
array([ 4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 20, 23,  0,  1,  2,  3,  6,  7,
       12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 21, 22, 24])
```

This solution is quite long, I guess one could come with a shorter/faster solution to this. Also here I just sorted the indexes according to their values but you could imagine any other ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have mentioned that `np.argsort` returns the indices that *would* sort an array, and that these indices depend on the sorting algorithm, for example:

```
>>> np.random.seed(0)  # for reproducibility
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 5, 20)
>>> np.argsort(a, kind='mergesort')
array([ 2,  6,  8, 11, 16,  0,  1,  3, 12, 17, 18, 19,  9,  5,  7, 10, 13,
       14, 15,  4])
>>> np.argsort(a, kind='quicksort')
array([ 2, 16, 11,  6,  8,  0, 17, 12, 18, 19,  3,  1,  9, 10,  5, 13, 14,
       15,  7,  4])
```

I'd like to go into *why*.

Briefly, sorting algorithms can be stable, or non-stable. Stability, in this context, means that they *do not change the relative order of elements that compare equal*.

Imagine that we "tag" elements with some value to show that they are different objects, for example:

```
unsorted = [4 (star), 3 (cube), 3 (star), 4 (cube)]
```

A stable sort, such as mergesort, will *always* return the following:

```
sorted = [3 (cube), 3 (star), 4 (star), 4 (cube)]
```

This is because `3 (cube)` came before `3 (star)` and `4 (star)` before `4 (cube)`.

Conversely, a non-stable sort, such as quicksort, could return the elements in any order, except that all the 3s must come before all the 4s.

When we apply this to our original problem, we can understand why it arose. Even though the elements have the same *value* (they compare equal), they do not have the same *identity* (they are different objects). Accordingly, within each "cluster" of equal objects, they may be ordered differently depending on the sorting algorithm.

Comment: That's interesting, I've always seen this _stable_ vs. _non-stable_ as an obscure thing (probably because I never really cared about ties before), but that's actually very simple, thanks for this explanation.